# Golang concurrent SSH connections

Tags: go, ssh, concurrency

I have multiple servers that I'm trying to establish SSH connections to, and I'm spawning a new goroutine for every SSH connection I have to establish. I then send some commands. This program sort of works, but just exits after the first connection.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("servers.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        go ssh_login(scanner.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func ssh_login(host string) {
    port := "22"
    user := "testing"
    pass := "testing"
    cmd := "uname -a"

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: user,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(pass),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),

        Timeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }

    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    sess, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer sess.Close()

    sess.Stdout = os.Stdout
    sess.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err = sess.Run(cmd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not waiting for the goroutines to end

Comment: tried it doesn't seem to fix the problem even without goroutines the problem still persists

Comment: What problem persists? What exactly happens when you execute the code if you wait for each command to run?